# How to use the re module to match the HTML code

Tags: html, python-3.x

i get the code:

```
<div class="content">
xxxxxx
</div>
```

i try to use the re moudle to matchmy code:

```
pattern=re.compile(r'<div class="content">(.*?)</div>')
items=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)#raw_data is html code
print(items)
```

the output:

```
items=[]
```

waht's wrong about my code.How can i solve this error?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions? *Use an HTML parser*, that's what they're there for!

Answer (score 1):

This may sound simple, but you should definitely *use an HTML Parser for HTML parsing*.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_data)
content = soup.find("div", class_="content")
print(content.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `raw_data` because this work correctly:

```
import re

raw_data='<div class="content">xxxxx</div>'

pattern=re.compile(r'<div class="content">(.*?)</div>')
items=re.findall(pattern,raw_data)
print(items)
```

output:

> ['xxxxx']

Comment: I should emphasize that the code between lines.sorry

Comment: or use replace: raw_data='<div class="content">\nxxxxx\n\nasd</div>'.replace('\n',' ')

Answer (score 0):

You are missing newline & whitespace characters in your regex:

```
<div class="content">\s*(.*?)\s*</div>
```